# Easiest way to run a group of cells in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Imagine that you have a very large number of groups of cells:

[image]

At some point you want to run a subgroup of cells.

There are multiple ways to do it. Some more convenient than others depending of whether you want to do that once or everyday.

Please post "your" way so we can all learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A] Select blocks (Ctrl+Click) and run selection with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]

---

---

[B] Place all the sub-blocks under a single top-level block and run it clicking the triangle on the left side.

This method requires to modify all the headers involved so they have a lower level than the top one.

[image]

```
# Level 1
## Level 1.1
### Level 1.1.1
```

Run

[image]

---

---

[C] Place an exception on the place you want to stop. Run *from* the start point selecting it and Ctrl+F10 (Run AFTER)

[image]

Note: Run after includes running the cell selected.